# What is meaning of different fields returned by get login form call?

Tags: yodlee

I am looking for specific meaning of following fields

- valueIdentifier
- valueMask
- fieldType
- FieldInfoMultiFixed
- AutoRegFieldInfoSingle
- FieldInfoMultiVariable

and in most cases we are getting numerical value for helpText. How do we identify whether helpText is present or not?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the stuff like FieldInfoMultiFixed/Variable is discussed in the Yodlee SDK Developer guide. Search for either one. They're just basically silly combos where people breakup a single value into multiple fields (like phone number or ssn into 3 textboxes)

As for the helpText, every time i've seen a Yodlee tech respond they say no. The number corresponds to an internal resource identifier that is apparently not exposed through the api. I want to say I saw somebody say that it might be available for things like forum signup/registration (where it would be more useful). The SDK makes mention as if it works as you would expect it to but that is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Yodlee does not have helptext populated for any field. Hence a numerical value is associated to it. In future if any helptext gets added then instead of numerical value you will have text in that field.
Hence if you are receiving numerical values then you should take it as helptext not present.

Shreyans

Comment: Are you sure?  If that's the case, what do the numerical values mean?  Is the lookup for the help text?